# Conflict: Constraint aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 is not satisfied by aldeed:autoform 5.3.2

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I am using **aldeed-autoform**, **cfs-autoform** and **meteoric** packages

It seems they are not compatible with each other

I have tried upgrading the package for aldeed-autoform to version 5.3.1
Below is the error message i received

**Errors while adding packages :**

> While selecting package versions:
>
> error: Conflict: Constraint aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 is not satisfied by
>   aldeed:autoform 5.3.2.
>
> Constraints on package "aldeed:autoform":
>
> - aldeed:autoform@5.3.1 <- top level
> - aldeed:autoform@4.2.0 <- meteoric:autoform-ionic 0.1.5
> - aldeed:autoform@4.0.0 || 5.0.0 <- cfs:autoform 2.2.1

From this error message i can understand that using meteoric-packages is supporting only autoform version - 4.2.0

But due to this cfs-autoform functions do not work.

Please check if there is anything that can be done here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to update the `meteoric:autoform-ionic` package to 0.1.6. This version supports 5.2.0 while the previous version supported 4.2.0